# React relative paths with npm start

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am trying to get react app (made with create react app) to run with npm start both locally and in a container that has routing that would require relative paths in index.html.

Specifically, with npm start, everything works fine by going to localhost:300.  In the generated source, I see a script being loaded from /static/js/bundle.js.

In my container, the site is accessed at mydomain.com/admin.  So, I need the script to be loaded from ./static/js/bundles.js.

I tried to set homepage in package.json to "./", but it doesn't seem to actually do anything.  I'm a bit new to this, and none of the answers I am finding seem relevant.  I did try ejecting, but that didn't change anything.